# BOOTSTRAP CSS photo wall to cover the page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to cover the entire page by small photos, but what i found is that i can't cause they leave some left and right margin in the page.

i'm not using js for doing that, just css and html:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="wrapper">
<div id="home-decore">

<img/>
<img/>
<img/>
<img/>
<img/>
<img/>
<img/>
<img/>
<img/>
<img/>
<img/>
etc ..



</div>
</div>

#wrapper{
  background:red;
    padding-top:5%;
min-height: 88%;
height: auto !important;
height: 88%;

}
#home-decore{
margin:0;
padding-top:60px;
left:0;
top:0;
position:realtive;
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
background:#000;


}
#home-decore img{
  border-radius:2px;
  border:0.3% solid white;
  opacity:0.6;
  width: 3.3333%; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
#home-decore img:hover{
opacity:1;
}
```

what i would like is to fit all the page right:0;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;

Comment: So are you just trying to scale the images to the screen so the number you specify fill the background or just fill the background with as many images as possible?

Comment: the first one, but i'm wondering how many photos and how much width to fit all :P , i don't want to leave margins (body margin) on right side as you can see, on left side they fit perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the number of images you have horizontally, then specify the width of each image as (100 / numHorizontalImages)%, and then do the same thing for height. It would look something like this if you had 10 images horizontally and 5 vertically:

`img { width: 10%; height: 20%;}`

Comment: what i mean is that is more complicated to cover the page, cause how can i set the img width to fit all the page on all screen resolutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that without using Bootstrap css

```
here's the Css code for it 
 <ul>
    <li style="float: left; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 15px">
  <img/>
   <li style="float: left; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 15px">
   <img/>
   </li>
  </li>
   ...........
 </ul>
```

And for the Image Border As Bootstrap provides refer to the following link

http://css-tricks.com/using-css-for-image-borders/

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a CSS Reset:

http://www.cssreset.com/

You could alternatively try adding something like this as a quick fix to the body element inside your CSS:

```
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

What happens is the browser defines some default values for padding & margin, I think this is what you're running into currently.

( Also noticed there's a typo in '#home-decore', 'realtive' should be 'relative', this may be providing unexpected results )